# Upgrading from Fedora 17 to Fedora 20 (or higher)

Tags: fedora, yum, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my fedora 17 install to a more recent version. I have tried the following methods, which don't work:

First, using fedup:

```
# yum install ./fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Examining ./fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm: fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch
Marking ./fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fedup.noarch 0:0.8.1-1.fc20 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: systemd >= 183 for package: fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch
---> Package preupgrade.noarch 0:1.1.10-2.fc17 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: preupgrade for package: PackageKit-0.7.6-1.fc17.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: PackageKit-0.7.6-1.fc17.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: preupgrade
           Removing: preupgrade-1.1.10-2.fc17.noarch (@koji-override-0/$releasever)
               preupgrade = 1.1.10-2.fc17
           Obsoleted By: fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch (/fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch)
               Not found
Error: Package: fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch (/fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch)
           Requires: systemd >= 183
           Installed: systemd-44-24.fc17.x86_64 (@updates)
               systemd = 44-24.fc17
           Available: systemd-44-8.fc17.i686 (fedora)
               systemd = 44-8.fc17
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 9 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
krb5-devel-1.10.2-12.fc17.x86_64 has missing requires of keyutils-libs-devel
krb5-devel-1.10.2-12.fc17.x86_64 has missing requires of libselinux-devel
libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with libdb-5.2.36-5.fc17.x86_64
1:openssl-1.0.1c-7.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:openssl-1.0.0k-1.fc17.x86_64
rpm-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-build-libs-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-build-libs-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-libs-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-libs-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-python-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-python-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
sqlite-3.7.11-3.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with sqlite-3.7.11-2.fc17.x86_64
```

Second, using yum:

```
# yum --releasever=21 distro-sync --nogpgcheck
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Distribution Synchronization Process
http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/fedora/fedora-21-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from pgdg93: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/fedora/fedora-21-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
```

So, my question is how I get fedup to install, or how I get yum to try a different mirror to upgrade?

"Don't do this" or "you can't do this" answers not required. The above methods are taken from the fedora documentation at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum#Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum_directly and https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp#How_Can_I_Upgrade_My_System_with_FedUp.3F

Comment: Why are you so dead set against doing a full install?  The results will definitely be cleaner and you will have a LOT less hassle.

Comment: @mdpc Because I know how to perform a fresh install. Indeed, I'm pursuing that in parallel. It's not especially convenient.